# Multiple protocol inheritance in Swift 2.0 using extension protocols

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, swift2, protocol-extension

Playing with the new extension protocols in Swift 2.0 come by this example:

```
protocol A {
  func foo()
}

protocol B {
  func foo()
}

extension A {
    func foo() { print("A") }
}

extension B {
    func foo() { print("B") }
}

class C: A, B {

}
```

Is something like a "*multiple inheritance*" , that some languages like Python and C++ can handle as multiple inheritance of course. What really surprise me was the two compile errors that Xcode 7.0 Beta 4 gave me:

> **Type 'C' does not conform to protocol 'A'**

---

> **Type 'C' does not conform to protocol 'B'**

But this error not make any sense because the error must reflect that exist conflict or ambiguity between protocol `A` and `B` regarding the use of the `foo` function, or something like that.

If you put below of the above code the following line :

```
C().foo()
```

This launches exactly the error type I talking about:

> **Ambiguous use of 'foo'**

My question here is :

With the new addition of extension protocols in Swift 2.0 has Apple considered any treatment to this kind of "*multiple inheritance*"(something like the way of C++ treatment) or just is not allowed at all?

Comment: @MartinR Is very much the same problem except for my question, I saw your answer and you're right ,but my question is different from the another question.

Comment: Then the answer is probably "it is just not allowed". What would you expect that `C().foo()` does?

Comment: Nothing, my question is posted because with the new addition of protocol extensions in the book of Swift , Apple has no mention at all about this topic and I would expect some clarification about the treatment it has for the Swift compiler, is for that my mention to C++ and Python, nothing more just curiosity.

Comment: Then I don't see why this is not a duplicate. That may be my fault, but perhaps you can clarify in your question what makes it different from the linked-to thread.

Comment: @MartinR it could be a duplicate , I think you're right after reading your answer once again.