# Marking methods as final in protocol extensions

Tags: swift, swift2

What are the implications of doing the following:

```
protocol A {
    func f()
}

extension A {
    final f() {}
}
```

I'm looking to understand what putting `final` in the extension over here does when compared to not putting it. I know what `final` does, I'm looking to understand overriding behaviour for classes implementing/not implementing `f` and their subclasses.

Answer (score 3):

You can no longer mark extension funcs as final.

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1762

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 2.0: [Protocol Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID521)

[Methods, properties, or subscripts that you add to a class in an extension can also be marked as final within the extension’s definition.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-ID202)

Referring to this question of [Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884741/multiple-protocol-inheritance-in-swift-2-0-using-extension-protocols?rq=1), final keyword would not allow to override the (final) method defined in Extension, when it's Sub-classed.

For Swift 1.2:
This might be useful in context of Extensions [Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)

Few things to look in context of Extensions, while decide on architecture of applications:

1. [Protocol's cannot be extended to Extension](http://swiftstub.com/546251634/?v=gm).
2. [It has go through a Class](http://swiftstub.com/280171983/?v=gm).
3. [Existing functionality cannot be overridden (invalid redeclaration of)](http://swiftstub.com/14092332/?v=gm)

On final keyword, this is my take it has no impact on Extensions methods as compared to classes(Inheritance). Please correct me if I'm wrong here.
Demo links:

1. [Protocol A-->Class B-->Extension B](http://swiftstub.com/747012680/?v=gm)
2. [Protocol A-->Class B-->Extension B, then Class B --> Class C](http://swiftstub.com/480933029/?v=gm)

Comment: Protocols do have extensions in Swift 2. The site is probably not updated yet.